# Access originalRouteTemplate and parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an application that will be dynamically configuring the RouteTable for ASP.NET Web API based on metadata. I will be routing all calls to a single action on a single controller that will also leverage that metadata to generate and provide a response.

The method I have to handle this currently has the following signature:

```
public IHttpActionResult Test(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    // This is where I need help...
}
```

I'm keen to leverage the existing routing capability of ASP.NET Web API and it would be great if inside this single method I could access the following:

- the original routeTemplate
- the value of any url parameters in a dictionary (key and value)

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can get this using

```
var rd = request.GetRouteData();
rd.RouteTemplate // the route template
rd.Values // dictionary of parameters (including controller and action)
```